How to use DeepLink with Xamarin Android (NOT FORMS)
I'm trying to implement DeepLink in my Android application. It was made using Xamarin, but not forms. It's an old application that I just can't redo. Every link just takes me to either Xamarin Forms stuff or Android Studio. Please, I need help. I tried using Intent but can't override OnAppLinkRequestReceived because the program says it can't find a suitable method.

Hi, welcome to SO. Please [edit] the question and show us the code that you tried and explain in what way it does not work: compile error / runtime error / incorrect result, etc. Without that you may not get much help. Also please see [ask].
